# C# How to return an instance of the type of subclass from function?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, class, inheritance

I have a bunch of classes that formulate various variations of items. I currently have a class like this:

```
public class Item {
    public ItemFile file { get; set;}
    public ItemCalendar calendar { get; set;}
    public ItemWebsite website { get; set;}
}
```

ItemFile etc are classes made using Entity Framework and map to the database tables that provide the information relating to that type of item. The item class only has one of the internal properties actually instantiated.

I can see the number of items growing to around 25 or more. I don't feel right making the view model containing 25 properties where 24 of them are null with only one being not null.

I want something that can work with entity framework and return a class that can return only it's actual type. Therefore if I ask for the variation of the item I would get back ItemFile for files and ItemCalendar for calendars.

I've tried something like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public ItemBase item { get; set; }
}

public class ItemBase
{
    public Type typeName { get; set; }
    public object ItemInstance { get; set; }

    public typeName GetInstance()
    {
        return Convert.ChangeType(ItemInstance, typeName);
    }
}
```

But then I don't know how to return ItemFile as public typeName is an error.

I then tried:

```
public class Item
{
    public ItemBase<ItemFile> item { get; set; }
}

public class ItemBase<T>
{        
    public T ItemInstance { get; set; }
}
```

But to get that to work, I had to hardcore FileItem in the <> on the item class which goes back into knowing the type before hand.

Is there anyway to get this to work? Bonus points if it can work with entity framework as I'm pulling back the classes from there. Worst comes to worst if it doesn't work entity framework wise is I can pull it all and then convert it into the form that answers the question.

If the title of the question is wrong, feel free to edit. I wasn't sure how to ask.

tl;dr version: I want to be able to return multiple types of classes from a function using a type that is passed in not using <>.

Edit 1:

I forgot to show my inheritence example. I've tried this but also got stuck with something similar to the above.

```
public class ItemBase
{
    public Type typeName { get; set; }
    public object ItemInstance { get; set; }

    public typeName GetInstance()
    {
        return Convert.ChangeType(ItemInstance, typeName);
    }
}

public class ItemFile : ItemBase

{
    public String FileName { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public void testFunction()
    {
        //Made this just so the compiler didn't complain.
        ItemFile testFile = new ItemFile();

        //I can use a function to get the item base.
        ItemBase baseItem = testFile;

        //How do I do this? Use a function to get the ItemFile from the instance.
        ItemFile finalItem = baseItem.GetInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the function that you talk about?

Comment: You probably want to look at inheritance (as your tags suggest) but your example code doesn't do that at all.

Comment: @DavidG I added my inheritance example.

Comment: Your last line just needs to be `ItemBase finalItem = (ItemBase)baseItem;`

Comment: @DavidG I believe you meant ItemFile instead of ItemBase? The problem however with what you presented is that I don't know that it is an ItemFile or an ItemWebsite etc. I would want a function that returns the proper type. If I want to manually check and cast it every time I pull it from the database, I believe then I could do what you proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to return multiple types of classes from a function using a type that is passed in not using <>.

<> (generics) are the mechanism by which a function can explicitly return more than one type. Without generics the function returns whatever type it says it returns.

```
object SomeFunction() // Returns an object

ItemBase SomeOtherFunction () // returns ItemBase
```

In the above examples, `SomeFunction` can still return any type (because all types inherit from `object`.) But it won't be explicit. All you know for sure is that it's an `object`.

Similarly, `SomeOtherFunction` can return an `ItemBase` or any class that inherits from `ItemBase`. But that's all you know about it.

Ideally you don't want to have functions returning one type (like `object` or `ItemBase`) and then cast the result of the function to another more specific type. The function should return what you want, and you should want what the function returns. Generics help with that. For example:

```
public TItem Instance<TItem>() where TItem : ItemBase
```

allows a function to return a specified type  as long as it is an `ItemBase` or inherits from one.

This last comment is going to seem odd or useless but it's the truth. If you find yourself in a scenario where the above rules don't work and you need to be able to do something that you can't do or shouldn't do, go back and rethink why you're trying to do that. That's where the real problem is.

That means you probably need to go back a step and get yourself out of the situation where you're trying to work against the language. What are you trying to accomplish and how can you do it in a way that works with the language, not against it?

Comment: I like the "where" part where you restricted it to ItemBase class only. I didn't know you could do that. I think all of this would work except for one part. Take what you presented: public TItem Instance<TItem>() where TItem : ItemBase. How would I call that for lets say ItemFile? I believe it's Instance<ItemFile>(). I don't know at the time of the call what it is to hardcore ItemFile. I can store the type however and I was wondering if you can pass the type variable into the function so Instance<TYPEVAR>()? I need someway to tell from the 25 types such as itemWebsite etc which to use.

Comment: I was thinking a function would work as I could put all the logic saying if this is an ItemFile then Instance<ItemFile>() but as I posted above, I wouldn't be able to return multiple types from that function so I would be in the same place.

Comment: This is the core of the problem: "I don't know at the time of the call what it is to hardcore ItemFile." If you're calling a function and you don't know what type you want it to return, then how do you know what to do with it when you get it? If you don't know that it's an `ItemFile`, that suggests that you're not going to call any methods specific to `ItemFile`. So why do you need it to return that specific type? That's why I'd step back from the problem you're trying to solve and figure out an approach where you don't need to solve that problem.

Comment: This is not unusual. We have all been exactly where you're at right now trying to solve pretty much the same problem. So trust me when I say, the answer isn't to solve it but rather to design code so that you don't need to solve that sort of problem. No matter how I say it it seems like something from a fortune cookie. But it's the truth.

Comment: "If you don't know that it's an ItemFile, that suggests that you're not going to call any methods specific to ItemFile." I would be calling methods specific to the 25 different cases. I'm guessing then the best thing to do is to store it all as an object, check the type to see what type the file is, and then make a switch statement off that type and then do the hard conversion you posted to then do my actions. Only thing that sucks about this is I have to reproduce that switch statement stuff in about 7 different files.

Comment: It still doesn't quite make sense. That means that you're going to call a method, get an object, and then depending on what type of object is returned call one of 25 different methods. Even if you didn't have to duplicate it, having that just once would be a problem. Why are 25 possible actions on 25 different types of objects all in one method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155273/discussion-between-solidsnake4444-and-scott-hannen).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is about as close as you're going to get.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EFTypeData itemData = GetItemData();
            var asmName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
            var type = Type.GetType($"ConsoleApplication1.{itemData.TypeName}, {asmName}");
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            var item = new Item<Object>()
            {
                ItemBase = instance 
            };
        }

        private static EFTypeData GetItemData()
        {
            return new EFTypeData() { TypeName = "ItemFile" };
        }
    }

    class EFTypeData
    {
        public string TypeName { get; set; }
    }

    class Item<T> where T: class
    {
        public T ItemBase { get; set; }
    }

    class ItemFile
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This will, given a string "ItemFile", create an instance and assign it to Item. If you run this and inspect `item`, you have
[image: debug output]

The big caveat to this is that at compile-time, all you have is an Object as your ItemBase. And without hard-coding your Type (i.e. `var item = new Item<ItemFile>();`), you're never going to know more.
That said, with this method you are perfectly clear to iterate over fields and such using Reflection. But this is a limitation of this level of run-time object manipulation.